# finding and placing number into a variable with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a several sentences in a file

```
Text1{489.15,274.3},text2{183.24,1.2},text3{192,1001}
```

How to collect values of text2 (183.24 and 1.2) to variables?

Comment: Try giving it an instruction: _hey you, collect my values_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various ways here. For example you could use a simple regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
my $text = q|Text1{489.15,274.3},text2{183.24,1.2},text3{192,1001}|;
my ($num1, $num2);

if ($text =~ m/text2\{(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)\}/) {
  $num1 = $1;
  $num2 = $2;
}
say $num1;
say $num2;
```

Or you could use a `split` like mpapec wrote as comment.

EDIT:

with this solution, its important how these numbers will look. For example if these numbers are not floats, its not working. But you gave us only 1 example, so its hard to say.
BTW: Please post your problems with code you tried...

Answer (score 1):

The first one is easy.

```
(?<=text2\{)[\-.\d]*
```

This first looks for "text2{", and then captures a number which follows that. A lookbehind like this needs a fixed length of the search string.
The number can be negative but there is the assumption that there are no stray spaces, no empty spots, and the numbers are very regular (eg not two decimal points or commas in between).
Try it [here](http://regexr.com?38332)

For the second part, you can capture it in groups, and exclude the parts before and after the one you want.
For example, search for

```
(.*?text2{[\-.\d]*,)([\-.\d]*)(.*)
```

and replace with $2.
This searches for all the characters until "text2{", followed by a number followed by a comma - which is all group 1.
Then it searches for a number (like before) - group 2. Then it takes in everything afterwards - group 3.
Groups 1 and 2 are discarded when you replace the whole thing with $2.
Try [here](http://regexr.com?3833b)